# this androied project give me a crash i am trying to make project that have a number from Edit text and get it in a text view times two

Tags: java, android, function

I want to  get the value that I enter from edit text to a text view *2 but the app crashes.

```
public  void sub (View v)
{
    int val=Integer.parseInt( e1.getText().toString());

    if(val <= 1)
    {
      t1.setText("you havn't ran any kilos");
    }
    else if(val > 1) {
        t1.setText(val*2);
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

t1.setText(val*2 + "");

because val is Integer type and setText method's param is String type.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public  void sub (View v)
{
int val=Integer.parseInt( e1.getText().toString());

if(val <= 1)
{
  t1.setText("you havn't ran any kilos");
}
else if(val > 1) {
    t1.setText(String.valueOf(val*2));
```

}